# Is it possible to assign a "run probability" to any function?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

if I had a random list of numbers:

```
d = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Is it possible to use `RandomSample`but only sample list "d" given a probability "x."  When you use `RandomSample` the probability of sampling is always guaranteed (i.e. you'll always have a sample as an output) but would it be possible so that `RandomSample` only works "x" percentage of time.

As an example if we take list "d", I want to perform `RandomSample` but the function only has a 30% chance of working.  So 30% of the time, it'll sample from list "d" and then 70% of the time, I don't have any samples being obtained.  Is there a simple way to perform this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fn = RandomChoice[{#3, 1 - #3} -> {RandomSample[#1, #2], {}}] &;
```

Use:

> fn[list,number_of_samples,probability_of_sample_success]

Example:

```
fn[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3, .3]
```

> {2,1,5}

```
fn[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3, .3]
```

> {1,4,5}

```
fn[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 3, .3]
```

> {}

Comment: @anton-antonov: Oops, looks like we had same basic idea, and you posted while I was typing. Happy to delete...

Comment: They are very similar, but different enough to keep both. (I think...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `RandomChoice` to do weighted random choice of the sampling functions and use `Through` to apply those functions to your data.

```
d = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

SeedRandom[15]
Through[RandomChoice[{0.7, 0.3} -> {RandomSample[#, 1] &, Nothing &}, 12][d]]

(* {{3}, {5}, {1}, {6}, {1}, {4}, {4}, {3}, {3}} *)

SeedRandom[15]
Through[RandomChoice[{0.7, 0.3} -> {RandomSample[#, 1] &, None &}, 12][d]]

(* {None, None, {3}, {5}, {1}, {6}, {1}, {4}, {4}, None, {3}, {3}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:

```
d = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

RandomChoice[
 Flatten@{70, ConstantArray[30/Length[d], Length[d]]} ->
  {{}, Sequence @@ d}
]
```

Let's check that it does what you want by drawing 10,000 samples:

```
RandomChoice[
  Flatten@{70, ConstantArray[30/Length[d], Length[d]]} ->
   {{}, Sequence @@ d},
  10000
] // Counts

(* Out: <|{} -> 6998, 3 -> 478, 2 -> 481, 1 -> 489, 5 -> 494, 4 -> 554, 6 -> 506|> *)
```

The frequency of `{}` (i.e. the "no sample" response) is 6998/10000, i.e.pretty close to 70%. The others are pretty evenly distributed as well.